# Formulário com Data e Hora - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime

Possuo um formulário com a opção para escolher data e Hora.
Estou utilizando os componentes Datepicker e Timepicker.

```
<!-- Date -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Data</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
      <input ng-model="alerta.data" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="dataHora">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Time -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Hora</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      </div>
      <input ng-model="alerta.hora" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="timePicker">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O problema que estou tendo é o seguinte, quando envio o formulário, não estou recebendo os valores alerta.hora e alerta.data no meu controller. O restante dos inputs do formulário recebe normalmente.

Segue JSON de retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a função que inicia os dois componentes:

```
vm.dateTimeRange = function() {
   $('#dataHora').datepicker({timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
   $('#timePicker').timepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou dar um attr dos inputs no Controller? 
Ex:

```
 vm.funcaoEnvio = function (alerta) {
  vm.dados = {
    'nome': alerta.nome,
    'email': alerta.email,
    'cidade': alerta.cidade,
    'telefone': alerta.telefone
  }
vm.dados.hora = $(".classe_do_teu_input-de_hora").attr('value');
vm.dados.data = $(".classe_do_teu_input_de_data").attr('value');
}
```

Depois você submita o vm.dados.

Você pode tratar o valor da data e hora utilizando também a biblioteca do [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Caso esteja precisando somente do mask de data/hora, você pode utilizar o [Angular-UI-Mask](https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/).